# Continue function after ajax request has been completed

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, request

I was wondering if it was possible to have a function call a function that has an ajax request, and continue executing when the ajax request finished. Here is example pseudo code.

```
function func1(){
    //do things
    func2();
    //**How would I get this code to execute after the ajax request is finished.
}

function func2(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.html",
        context: document.body,
        success: function(){
            //do some things
        }
    });
```

I do not want to execute everything in a callback function, as this function is called many times in a loop.

Thanks!

Comment: The only option to exactely meet your wishes is by using a synchronous request. This method is discouraged though. Also, duplicate of many other questions.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to create a workaround that would execute a function after all ajax requests were complete.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices.

1. Use a callback function for the processing that happens after the AJAX call.
2. Use a synchronous "JAX" call ... remember, the A in AJAX is Asynchronous.

Otherwise, there's not a good way to accomplish what you describe.